# Golang | Handle duplicate declaration on import

Tags: go, import, duplicates

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/HewlettPackard/docker/api/client"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)
```

Here, focues on these 2 specific libs :

```
"github.com/HewlettPackard/docker/api/client"       
"github.com/docker/docker/client"
```

both of them return a "client",
how can I override name of one of those 2 and use both the libraries at once.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can specify a "local" package name in the import declaration, e.g. `dc "github.com/docker/docker/client"` and then you would reference that package as `dc`. See: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a name to each package in the following way -

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    hpclient "github.com/HewlettPackard/docker/api/client"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    dockerclient "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)
```

Now you can use the names `hpclient` or `dockerclient` while accessing the packages. You can use any names which are comfortable for you.